# How can I find out in mysql 8 which process execute a delete statement and at what time?

Tags: mysql

I use version 8 of mysql. I am looking for an unknown process which delete rows in a table. How can I monitor this in mysql over a longer time?

Comment: You can turn on the general query logger, but be aware, it logs a lot on busy servers.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `AFTER DELETE` trigger with the [USER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_user) function:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_to_audit (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE table_to_audit_delete_log (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    deleted_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
    deleted_by VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TRIGGER table_to_audit_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON table_to_audit
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO table_to_audit_delete_log VALUES (OLD.id, NOW(), USER());

INSERT INTO table_to_audit VALUES (1, 'Joe'), (2, 'Jane'), (3, 'John'), (4, 'Jess');
SELECT * FROM table_to_audit;

DELETE FROM table_to_audit WHERE id = 2;
SELECT * FROM table_to_audit_delete_log;
```

This will probably only be useful if your users/applications authenticate with their own user accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the general log.  Periodically "rotate" it.  Check the file that is pushed aside, then delete it.  That way, you won't miss the DELETE and won't fill up disk.

I don't know the 'official' way to rotate, but I think this will work:

```
(in shell) mv ...log sav.log
(in MySQL) FLUSH LOGS;
(by hand)  review sav_log
(in shell) rm sav.log
```